# VBA Click Button

Tags: vba, excel, web-scraping, click

Using VBA, how can I click the orange LOGIN button on the below page:
https://www.solaraccreditation.com.au/login.html

Inspect element shows: 
`<input class="button bg-orange" value="Login" type="submit">`

So far my code is:

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare Sub ShowWindow Lib "user32" _
    (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal nCmdShow As Long)

Const strTMP As String = "Excel VBA"
Private Const SW_MAXIMIZE = 3

Public Sub Test()
    Dim objWindow As Object
    Dim objIEApp As Object
    Dim objShell As Object
    Dim objItem As Object
    Dim objInputs As Object
    Dim ele As Object

    On Error GoTo Fin
    Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    Set objWindow = objShell.Windows()
    For Each objItem In objWindow
        If LCase(objItem.FullName Like "*iexplore*") Then
            Set objIEApp = objItem
        End If
    Next objItem
    If objIEApp Is Nothing Then
        Set objIEApp = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
        objIEApp.Visible = True
    End If
    With objIEApp
        .Visible = True
        ShowWindow .hWnd, SW_MAXIMIZE
        .Navigate "https://www.solaraccreditation.com.au/login.html"
        While Not .ReadyState = 4
            DoEvents
        Wend
            .document.All("username").Value = _
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Range("a1")
            .document.All("password").Value = _
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Range("a2")
    End With
 '       <input class="button bg-orange" type="submit" value="Login"  />

Fin:
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then MsgBox "Error: " & _
        Err.Number & " " & Err.Description
    Set objWindow = Nothing
    Set objShell = Nothing
End Sub
```

Mary Poppins "Classic Disney" soundtrack. ... Um diddle diddle, diddle um, diddle ay x2 ? Now, you can say it backwards, which is docious-ali-expi-listic-frag

i-cali-rupus.

Comment: "...simply quite atrocious!"

Answer (score 1):

You could try identifying the button as the first in its class.

```
.document.getelementsbyclass("button bg-orange")(0).click
```

But it might be more expedient to simply force the form to submit.

```
.document.getelementbyid("loginForm").submit
```